# Is there a way to take variables generated from VBA to Python?

Tags: python, excel, vba

I have a Python Script that reads data from Excel.

I have successfully created a Macro that is able to call that Python script and run it.

My problem is that the Excel File has to be in a **certain path** in order for the Python to find it.

I have defined in the VBA that the `file_path = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName`.

Great. Now I have the path of the `ActiveWorkbook`. How do I feed this path into Python?

As I call my Python function in VBA, I want to be able to feed this path so it reads this `ActiveWorkbook`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How are you calling the Python script from Excel? Can't you pass it as an argument somehow?

Comment: In VBA, I define a shell object "Wscript" and then give it the PythonExe and PythonScript Path - I'm having trouble passing in the FilePath as an argument into the Python. Not quite sure how to establish that connection

Comment: Try adding the file path following the Python script's path. This will look like a command-line argument to Python which you can retrieve from the `sys.argv` list in the Python script.

Comment: Would be very helpful to include the code where you call Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your VBA:

```
FilePath = """" & Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName & """"

Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run PythonExe & PythonScript & FilePath
```

In your python file:

```
import sys

file_path = sys.argv[1]
```

Comment: Not working for me. I have everything up to `oShell.Run PythonExe & " " & PythonScript & " " & FilePath` as you suggested.

Comment: XLRDerror: Unsupported format, or corrupt file,: Expected BDF record; found b'# -*- co*

Comment: It's breaking at 
`file_path = sys.argv[1]`
`pd.read_excel(file_path)`

Comment: Also would `objShell.Run PythonExe & " " & PythonScript & " " & FilePath` be better in the VBA? Rather than the + operator. I'm not quite sure what's the difference

Comment: @confused_intern yes it would be better I think. I am more of a pythoner :)

Comment: Can you `print(file_path)` to see what is in it? I think it might be not the right type.

Comment: Okay I see what's happening. I have spaces in my file_path and everytime there is a space it's a new item in the list. I believe this is why I needed 3 quotation marks instead of 1 if my path has spaces. For example my PythonScript has spaces in the path so I do `PythonScript = """C;/ some path / etc"""` but my `PythonExe` path has no spaces so I simply do in VBA `"PythonExe = "C:/somepath/"` with one quote.

Comment: my solution was just doing: `FilePath = """" & Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName & """"` this way it looks like this: `"""C:/somepath with spaces"""` and now the string has 3 quotes. and sys.argv[1] is correct. Thanks a lot internet friend